# Python: Groupby hour include null values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

Using citibike data: https://s3.amazonaws.com/tripdata/index.html

```
tripduration    starttime   stoptime    start_station_id    start_station_name  start_station_latitude  start_station_longitude end_station_id  end_station_name    end_station_latitude    end_station_longitude   bikeid  usertype    birth_year  gender
461 2016-02-01 00:00:08 2016-02-01 00:07:49 480 W 53 St & 10 Ave    40.766697   -73.990617  524 W 43 St & 6 Ave 40.755273   -73.983169  23292   Subscriber  1966.0  1
297 2016-02-01 00:00:56 2016-02-01 00:05:53 463 9 Ave & W 16 St 40.742065   -74.004432  380 W 4 St & 7 Ave S    40.734011   -74.002939  15329   Subscriber  1977.0  1  
280 2016-02-01 00:01:00 2016-02-01 00:05:40 3134    3 Ave & E 62 St 40.763126   -73.965269  3141    1 Ave & E 68 St 40.765005   -73.958185  22927   Subscriber  1987.0  1
```

Using the Groupby function grouping by hour, I would like to include null values as zero.

I used the following code:

```
bikes_parked = df.groupby(['end_station_name',pd.Grouper(key='stoptime',freq='H')]).size().reset_index()
bikes_parked.rename(columns={0: 'bikes_parked'},inplace=True)
```

Which returned number of bikes parked by the hour, but for the hours that did not have data it skipped.

Output:

```
    end_station_name    stoptime               bikes_parked
0   1 Ave & E 15 St     2016-02-01 00:00:00    1
1   1 Ave & E 15 St     2016-02-01 05:00:00    1
2   1 Ave & E 15 St     2016-02-01 06:00:00    3
```

I want to include stoptime 01, 02, 03, 04 with bikes_parked as 0 as well.

Comment: Can you share a small subset of data you're working with?

Try a `df = df.fillna(0)` before `groupby`.

Comment: You don't have any additional constraints? Just want to fill na's with zero? Then `bikes_parked = df.fillna(0).groupby([...` should work.

Comment: @ayhan - Sorry I did not include the original data. df only includes stoptime when a trip is finished. So fillna(0) on df did not work because there were no na values.

Comment: Oh boy, I don't think pandas can generate these rows if the data doesn't exist. You will probably have to do it yourself. My suggestion is to create a dataframe with a full range of hours, all set to bikes_parked=0, and then update it with the relevant data from the grouped table using df.loc[bikes_parked.index, 'bikes_parked'] = bikes_parked.bikes_parked

Comment: @Shovalt - Thanks! That's what I ended up doing. I created another dataframe and did an outer merge.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, the solution is as such:

1) Create a DataFrame with a full range of hours, all set to `bikes_parked=0`

2) Update this DF with the relevant data from the grouped table by using:

```
df.loc[bikes_parked.index, 'bikes_parked'] = bikes_parked.bikes_parked
```